# iOs - How to store enum values and reuse-it

Tags: ios, enums

I want use an array to set a combination of enum

So i have an NSArray with several integers.

For example i want to do this:

```
[self setCachePolicy:ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy|ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
```

But with an NSArray !

an idea?

Comment: Do you mean a C array or an `NSArray`?

Comment: For iOs, so an NSArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be it.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @(ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy), @(ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy) ];
int combo = 0;

for (NSNumber *box in myArray) {
    combo |= [box intValue];
}

[self setCachePolicy:combo];
```